# Hiding some transaction data

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, quorum

I want to add data in Quorum that are visible only to specific users,

how could i implement that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `privateFor:` parameter. More details here. https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Using-Quorum#creating-private-transactionscontracts

Hope it helps.